# mySQL subquery question

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm normally determined to work these types of things out on my own but my mySQL skills are only basic and this has got me confused.

Basically I'm looking to select a number of titles that have reviews about them within a certain category. I then want to display the results, but display the average score for that title (and the number of reviews) based upon ALL categories of reviews and not just the selected one - the selected one is just to be used to show those titles that do have reviews in those categories.

Here's the code as it stands where it works but only displays the avg score and review count for those reviews matching the chosen category.

```
SELECT t.*, ROUND(AVG(r.rating)) as rating,
COUNT(r.rating) as ratingscount
FROM `titles` t LEFT JOIN `reviews` r ON t.titleid = r.titleid
WHERE approved = '1' AND category = 'category'
GROUP BY t.titleid ORDER BY rating DESC, ratingscount DESC limit 0, 10
```

Any help would be much appreciated and stop me losing any more of my already diminished hair!

Comment: Please describe your data structure.  What are your tables and what columns do they have?

Comment: These sound like two different queries to me: one to select titles within a category, and a second to display the score across all categories. Combining them will get messy fast.

Comment: There's a lot of columns to be honest, all I need to show for simplicity is "title" from titles table and then the rating and ratingscount as generated.

The reviews table (in terms of what is searched on) has a rating field and a category field.

Is that enough information?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by more than one field so try...

```
    GROUP BY t.titleid, category
```

...for starters